# C++ Do-While loop for Menu. Testing both uppercase and lowercase:

Tags: c++, loops, menu, switch-statement, do-while

I'm writing a do-while menu for a code. It uses a switch statement. 
The question I have regards the **while**. I need the code to only run when the user enters uppercase A - F, or lowercase a - f. Right now, the while statement only works with uppercase. I somehow need to make it work for the lowercase as well.

Here's the code:

```
//display menu
do
{
    cout << "A. Get the number of values entered \n"
    << "B. Get the sum of the vaules \n"
    << "C. Get the average of the values \n"
    << "D. Get the largest number \n"
    << "E. Get the smallest number \n"
    << "F. End the program \n"
    << "Enter your choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    while (choice < 'A' || choice >'F')
    {
        cout << "Please enter a letter A through F: ";
        cin >> choice;
    }
    if (choice != 'F' || 'f')
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'a': cout << "Number of numbers is: " << numCount << endl;
                break;
            case 'B':
            case 'b': cout << "Sum of numbers is: " << sum << endl;
                break;
            case 'C':
            case 'c': cout << "Average of numbers is: " << average << endl;
                break;
            case 'D':
            case 'd' : cout << "Max of numbers is: " << max << endl;
                break;
            case 'E':
            case 'e': cout << "Min of numbers is: " << min << endl;
                break;
            default: cin >> c;
        }

    }
    else      
    {

        cin >> c;
    }
}

while (choice !='F' || 'f');

return 0;
```

Comment: This: `while (choice !='F' || 'f')` isn't doing what you think it does. It essentially evaluates to `while(true)` by any reasonable optimizing compiler. It should be `while (choice !='F' && choice != 'f')`. Likewise for `if (choice != 'F' || 'f')`, which again, will optimize to simply `if (true)`.

Comment: Look up `std::tolower` or `std::toupper` to covert your characters and text to one case before you do comparisons.  It will simplify your program.  Also, search the web for "std::transform toupper" for an example of converting a string.

Comment: @WhozCraig please put that as an answer, I'll upvote :D

Comment: @P0W the OP is asking about character conversion to upper/lower case, thus it isn't an answer to their question, it is more an comment on their syntax. if they get a handle on their actual question the solution will fix them both as a side-effect. But in short, it isn't an answer to their question, and as such I posted a comment. hope that makes sense.

Comment: @WhozCraig- I see what you did there! Thank you. But every time I type lowercase 'b', the "Please enter a letter A - F" comes up. How do I make it incorporate the lower case values.

Comment: @JohnDAngelo Good. Now if we get you a conversion answer it will become a non-issue, but its good you understand what was wrong.

Comment: while (choice < 'A' || choice <'a' || choice < 'f' || choice >'F') Does not work. I've tried.

Comment: If I get of the While statement and change the default to cout << "Please enter a letter A through F: "; It'll work!

Comment: Work out all the boolean logic on paper.

Answer (score 3):

First, condition `choice != 'F' || 'f'` is wrong.
Correct condition is `((choice != 'F') && (choice != 'f'))`.

For work with lowercase you may use this condition in `while` loop:

```
while (! ((choice >= 'a' && choice <= 'f') || (choice >= 'A' && choice <= 'F')))
```

or use `toupper`/`tolower` functions from `ctype.h`

Answer (score 0):

Version 1

```
while ( (choice < 'a' || choice > 'f') && (choice < 'A' || choice > 'F') )
```

Version 2

```
while(choice < 'A' && choice > 'F')
{
    std::cin>>choice;
    choice = toupper(choice);
}
```

Hope that helps